# django use value of a link parameter in a template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I need to use a parameter in a link inside a template 
for example if my url link is

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/app1/factory/toyota/
```

the url for this link in the urlpatterns in urls.py is:

inside my template with the same link I just mentioned above I tried :

1-

`{% if 'factory' in request.GET %}
 <h1>my {{request.GET.factory}}</h1>
{% endif%}`

and tried

2-

```
{% if request.GET.factory %}
<h1> {{request.GET.factory}}</h1>
{% endif%}
```

and tried

3-

```
 {{request.GET.factory}}
```

4-
a)I added this function inside listview in views.py

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(WorkerListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs) 
    context['factory'] = self.request.GET.get('factory')
    return context
```

b)in the template I inserted this line:

```
<h1>my factory is {{factory}}</h1>
```

and the result was

```
my factory is None
```

Why it is returning none?? While I can see factory has a value in the link??

in the first 3 trials nothing appear in my page
in the fourth it is returning None.
I am expecting value Toyota to be returned in my page??

.....any ideas??what am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: GET parameters must be prefixed with a `&`: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/app1/&factory=toyota/` or `http://127.0.0.1:8000/app1&factory=toyota/`

Comment: how to do that ..I just add factory= before the slug in the url....so my url in urlpatterns look like this `path('factory=<slug:factory>/',views.WorkerListView.as_view(),name='worker_list'),` is there another way to this in the right way?

Comment: so I edited my urls so my link is as follow: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/app1/&factory=toyota/` . I added this function inside listview in views.py  `def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(WorkerListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context[factory] = self.request.GET.get(factory)
        return context`    . in the template  I inserted this line `<h1>my factory is {{factory}}</h1>` and the result was my factory is None.   Why it is returning none?? While I can see factory has a value??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `request.GET` with `kwargs` in views.py under the listview:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(WorkerListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs) 
    context['factory'] = self.kwargs.get('factory')
    return context
```

then use factory in your template like:

```
<h1>factory is {{factory}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex path:

```
 path('factory/<slug:factory>/',views.WorkertListView.as_view(),name=worker_list'),
```

and you need to call your url this way : `http://127.0.0.1:8000/app1/factory/toyota`

No need to extend thing, it will work

Comment: I got 'WSGIRequest' object is not subscriptable error when I tried this..thanks though

Comment: @SalamQais, your right i corrected my answer, and add a correct url, if not can you add your url pattern plz

Comment: ..yeh that's similar to what I tried before (point 4 in my post)..surprisingly iy returned None !!! ..the url is as follows: `path('&factory=<slug:factory>/',views.WorkertListView.as_view(),name=worker_list'),`  . do you think setting the value of   &factory=   manually is not correct way to do this? if so. do you know how to set values to a slug or pk in the url in order to use it later in the template? and thanks for your follow up

Comment: the problem is your path, you need to change it, i update my answer